# iPhone Objective-C image manipulation

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am looking for a way to, in Objective-C, create a PNG from several smaller PNGs based on how the user sets things up. Is this possible using existing Apple classes, or do I need to use a 3rd party library? If 3rd party code is needed, can anyone recommend a good library? The simpler the better - simple filters (such as darkening/lightening the image) would be nice but not required.

Here is some pseudo-code, to give you a better idea of what I am looking for:

```
image = [myImageLibrary imageWithHeight:1024 width:768];
[image addImage:@"background.png" atX:0 andY:0 withRotation:0];
[image addImage:@"image2.png" atX:100 andY:200 withRotation:90];
[image saveAtLocation:@"output.png"];
```

At output.png we see image2.png placed on top of background.png and rotated 90 degrees

P.S. - I am sorry if this seems to be a duplicate of another question, I just have not found an answer that works for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the "Creating and Drawing Images" section of the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Images/Images.html) and the [UIImage Class Reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIImage)?

What you're after is perfectly possible - with a well built class you could pretty much use that pseudo code as-is.

As a starter for ten, you could:

1. Create your own graphics context via `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.
2. Draw into that via the `drawAtPoint`: method of the [UIImage class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. Save the resultant image data out via `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`.

In terms of steps 1 and 3, see the [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) for more info. Additionally, the `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` method of the [UIImage class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) may prove useful for performing transformations, etc. as a part of step 2.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at CGContextDrawImage to draw your images, using a custom bitmap context, and then save it out using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(). The rotation can be done by applying CGAffineTransforms to your CGContext.

More information on Core Graphics here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html